# display login error using Ajax and Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

I'm developing a little application using Grails + Twitter BootStrap for the UI. In my index page, I have a form to login :

```
<g:form controller="user" action="login" id="form-login">
   <h2>Please, log in</h2>
   <g:textField name="userName" placeholder="Email address"/>
   <g:passwordField name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   <button id="submitConnection" type="submit">Connection</button>
</g:form>
```

Here, is my user controller :

```
def login(){
    String userName = params.userName
    String password = params.password

    User user = userName ? User.findByUserName(userName) : null
    //If login succeed
    if(user?.password == password){
        session.user = user
        redirect(action: 'index')
    }
    //If login failed
    else{
        render 'Email or password incorrect.'
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use Ajax through JQuery. I'm not familiar with Ajax/JQuery, so I'm not sure that I'm doing well things. In fact, I would like to do an Ajax request on click on the submit button. So I wrote this in my js :

```
$('#submitConnection').click(function() {
  var request = $.ajax({
      url: "/user/login",
      data: { userName: "dummy", password: "dummy"}
  });

  request.done(function ( data ) {
      if( data ) {
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      });
});
```

I would like when the login fails to fill in a div with an error message like 'login failed' and if it succeeds, just redirect to the index. I think I have to use JQuery to do this. Am I wrong ?

I don't really know what I have to modify/add in my controller to send something to the Ajax.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, dealing with your controller, sending a redirect back to an ajax request won't really suffice.  And when the auth fails, how does your javascript know?  So we should adjust your controller code a bit:

```
def login(){
    String userName = params.userName
    String password = params.password

    User user = userName ? User.findByUserName(userName) : null
    //If login succeed
    if(user?.password == password){
        session.user = user
        render(contentType: 'text/json') {
          [success: true, message: 'Login successful']
        }
    }
    //If login failed
    else{
        render(contentType: 'text/json') {
          [success: false, message: 'Email or Password incorrect']
        }
    }
}
```

Now as to your javascript, I'd start here:

```
$('#submitConnection').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents normal event of button submitting form
  $.post("/user/login", {userName: "dummy", password: "dummy"}, function(data) {
     if (data.success) {
        window.location = "some/path"; 
     } else {
        $("#error-message").html(data.message).show(); 
     }
  });
});
```

And then your HTML:

```
<g:form controller="user" action="login" id="form-login">
   <h2>Please, log in</h2>
   <div id="error-message" class="hide"></div>
   <g:textField name="userName" placeholder="Email address"/>
   <g:passwordField name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   <button id="submitConnection" type="submit">Connection</button>
</g:form>
```

Comment: Well, I tried with your code and now when the login succeed or fail, I'm always getting some JSON with success = true/false and the message. I'm probably missing something... but what ?

Comment: Yes, you're getting JSON in the response.  You're supposed to get JSON in the response. The javascript code I provided deals with that response by either redirecting the page on success, or displaying an error message.

Comment: Yes, I modify the javascript to go to the index page in case of success and I didn't modify anything in the else case. But every in every case, I'm getting a JSON page so the error message isn't displayed and the redirect doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ah, I know what the problem is.  Look at my edit in the js for e.preventDefault();

Comment: It works as expecting. Now I have to find how to proper redirect to my index.gsp .I upvoted your answer. Thanks again !